How to make XAxis less crowded and not display all dates on spline chart using highcharts
I have a spline chart that is generated with Highcharts. How to make the x-axis less crowded? This is a month's worth of data. Sometimes the data can be more than that. On the x-axis, sow only few dates rather than all of them.
My code:


Highcharts.chart('container', {
  "chart": {
    "backgroundColor": "#000",
    "type": "spline",
    "zoomType": "x"
  },
  "accessibility": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "legend": {
    "enabled": true,
    "itemStyle": {
      "color": "#ffffff"
    }
  },
  "rangeSelector": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "navigator": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "scrollbar": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "categories": ["Apr 2, 2024", "Apr 3, 2024", "Apr 4, 2024", "Apr 5, 2024", "Apr 6, 2024", "Apr 7, 2024", "Apr 8, 2024", "Apr 9, 2024", "Apr 10, 2024", "Apr 11, 2024", "Apr 12, 2024", "Apr 13, 2024", "Apr 14, 2024", "Apr 15, 2024", "Apr 16, 2024", "Apr 22, 2024", "Apr 17, 2024", "Apr 26, 2024", "Apr 27, 2024", "Apr 29, 2024", "Apr 30, 2024"],
    "labels": {
      "style": {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }
    },
    "lineColor": "#ffffff",
    "lineWidth": 3
  },
  "yAxis": [{
    "gridLineColor": "#000",
    "lineColor": "#fff",
    "lineWidth": 3,
    "labels": {
      "style": {
        "color": "#fff"
      }
    },
    "title": {
      "text": ""
    },
    "opposite": false
  }, {
    "title": {
      "text": "",
      "color": "#fff"
    },
    "opposite": true,
    "gridLineColor": "#000",
    "lineColor": "#fff",
    "lineWidth": 3,
    "labels": {
      "style": {
        "color": "#fff"
      }
    }
  }],
  "tooltip": {
    "backgroundColor": "#283347",
    "style": {
      "color": "#fff"
    },
    "shared": true,
    "useHTML": true
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "series": {
      "fillOpacity": 0,
      "marker": {
        "enabled": false,
        "states": {
          "hover": {
            "enabled": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "series": [{
    "name": "visits",
    "data": [{
      "name": "Apr 2, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 2182294
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 3, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 2139585
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 4, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 2104361
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 5, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 2202831
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 6, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 2180398
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 7, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 2231004
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 8, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 2187912
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 9, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 2203672
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 10, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 2186452
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 11, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 2187167
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 12, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 2248419
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 13, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 2423452
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 14, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 2499690
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 15, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 2402717
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 16, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 2397309
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 22, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 2393551
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 17, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 3348
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 26, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 4419054
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 27, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 2278264
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 29, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 2229568
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 30, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 2293853
    }],
    "color": "#DA70D6",
    "yAxis": 0
  }, {
    "name": "return_visits",
    "data": [{
      "name": "Apr 2, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1720977
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 3, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1698864
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 4, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1677394
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 5, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1749105
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 6, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1718534
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 7, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1752510
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 8, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1743050
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 9, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1738325
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 10, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1721808
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 11, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1733612
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 12, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1762564
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 13, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1907262
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 14, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1916476
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 15, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1882079
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 16, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1846960
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 22, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1827737
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 17, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1831
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 26, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 3565753
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 27, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1801874
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 29, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1776895
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 30, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1761887
    }],
    "color": "#FFD700",
    "yAxis": 0
  }, {
    "name": "unique_visitors",
    "data": [{
      "name": "Apr 2, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1578941
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 3, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1544172
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 4, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1517705
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 5, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1603987
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 6, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1588428
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 7, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1615074
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 8, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1573398
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 9, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1612672
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 10, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1590694
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 11, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1576982
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 12, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1598907
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 13, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1698120
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 14, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1793186
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 15, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1702037
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 16, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1721280
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 22, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1735671
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 17, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 2691
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 26, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 3124829
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 27, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1640897
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 29, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1566275
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 30, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1651959
    }],
    "color": "#6B8E23",
    "yAxis": 0
  }, {
    "name": "article_views",
    "data": [{
      "name": "Apr 2, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 863219
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 3, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 834750
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 4, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 787435
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 5, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 857901
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 6, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 855943
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 7, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 871373
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 8, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 849347
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 9, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 874912
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 10, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 893765
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 11, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 878446
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 12, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 948741
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 13, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 938141
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 14, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 938447
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 15, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 971806
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 16, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1005188
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 22, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1062300
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 17, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 2583
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 26, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 1725505
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 27, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 937386
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 29, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 856214
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 30, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 969535
    }],
    "color": "#FF7F50",
    "yAxis": 0
  }, {
    "name": "audio_play",
    "data": [{
      "name": "Apr 2, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 158735
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 3, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 166061
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 4, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 148663
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 5, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 133487
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 6, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 136010
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 7, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 160773
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 8, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 162092
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 9, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 153291
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 10, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 157931
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 11, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 145839
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 12, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 140483
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 13, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 170573
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 14, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 177091
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 15, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 180538
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 16, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 171497
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 22, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 180906
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 17, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 395
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 26, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 269944
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 27, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 141954
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 29, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 155965
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 30, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 153210
    }],
    "color": "#20B2AA",
    "yAxis": 0
  }, {
    "name": "video_play",
    "data": [{
      "name": "Apr 2, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 479844
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 3, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 495244
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 4, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 553062
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 5, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 445209
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 6, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 406745
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 7, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 452514
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 8, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 447724
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 9, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 435157
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 10, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 482781
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 11, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 478997
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 12, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 529373
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 13, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 783667
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 14, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 808305
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 15, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 660943
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 16, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 620450
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 22, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 497454
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 17, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 13202
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 26, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 873312
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 27, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 514325
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 29, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 551823
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 30, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 532816
    }],
    "color": "#FF8C00",
    "yAxis": 0
  }, {
    "name": "time_spent_per_visit",
    "data": [{
      "name": "Apr 2, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 298753508
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 3, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 295428214
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 4, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 289698259
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 5, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 281628634
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 6, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 276325393
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 7, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 298815690
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 8, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 300802278
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 9, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 287960174
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 10, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 299063477
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 11, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 311131007
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 12, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 310822626
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 13, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 347487659
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 14, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 356177362
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 15, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 340235250
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 16, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 330655491
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 22, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 322284004
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 17, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 767692
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 26, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 590347951
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 27, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 292822482
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 29, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 311850281
    }, {
      "name": "Apr 30, 2024 8:00 PM",
      "y": 301374165
    }],
    "color": "#ff0000",
    "yAxis": 1
  }]
});
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
   
</figure>



Here is the link to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nb_nb_nb/a6w2hntx/2/

To make the xAxis "less crowded" you can use xAxis.tickInterval option and set it to 2 or 3. This setting means that every second or third label will be displayed.
API references:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval
Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bo4pqxnt/
xAxis:{
 tickInterval: 2,
 ...
}

